# I cant install httpster using npm via CMD

Tags: node.js, npm, cmd, npm-install

I can't seem to install the httpster using npm on my local pc. It's always throwing an error as described below. I've tried using administrator CMD but still, it throws the same error. And I've also tried to install with the same directory as my installed npm. Kindly help how to resolve this :

**error**

> : npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/httpster failed,
>   reason: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "Host:
>   registry.npmjs.org. is not in the cert's altnames:
>   DNS:a.sni.fastly.net, DNS:a.sni.global-ssl.fastly.net"

[image: Error in CMD]

Comment: ive used npm -g install httpster as my command

Answer (score 0):

There's currently an issue with npmjs.com's DNS configuration. From it's current status page:

> An earlier outage involving a DNS misconfiguration has lead to some ISPs caching npmjs.com as missing, a workaround for this is to use a third party DNS provider such as Cloudflare or Google, the affected caches should clear within the next 24 hours.
>
> An alternative to using a different public DNS provider (like Google or CloudFlare) is to look up an IP address for `www.npmjs.com` and add it to your hosts file:
>
> 1. To look up an IP for `www.npmjs.com`, either use Google Public DNS or the command line with `dig` and CloudFlare's DNS:
>
>    ```
>    dig www.npmjs.com @1.1.1.1
>    ```
> 2. Add the IP address to your /etc/hosts file.
>
> Please note: to avoid issues if the resolved IP address changes, we strongly advise that you remove this entry from your hosts file after the weekend.

Generally, you can check the status of npm by going to https://status.npmjs.org/